# Confusion due to shared keystore of Mist and Ethereum Wallet

Tags: mist, keystore

I wasn't aware of the fact that Mist and Ethereum Wallet would use the same Geth and keys in the background and as a result made a big mistake to operate them at the same time...

So now there's the following weird situation, which I am trying to understand:

Scenario 1:

1. Open Ethereum Wallet (mainnet)
2. I can see an "Account 1" with 0 ETH
3. Status: Remote, 8,xxx,xxx blocks, last block xx seconds ago

Scenario 2:

1. Open Mist on testnet (Ropstein)
2. Open Ethereum Wallet (mainnet)
3. I can see an "Account 2" in Ethereum Wallet with 0.09xxx ETH (https://etherscan.io/address/0x72c674E4FE33C71D839a81d925ec618962320fd0)
4. Status in Ethereum Wallet: Remote, 8,xxx,xxx blocks, xx minutes ago (this does never update, just keeps going up)
5. Try to transfer it out: "Insufficient funds for gas * price + value", I get this error even if I only transfer 0.04 and have plenty of ETH left

What is happening?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue is a result of operating Mist and Ethereum Wallet in parallel as they are sharing geth in the background (MacOS).

Once I realized Mist / Ethereum Wallet are saving the keystore files in different folders depending if they are for the main or test network, it was easy to solve. Ethereum Wallet miscalculates/overestimates the gas price, so you just need to find a way to use a different wallet by copying the keystore file from test folder to e.g. MyCrypto to open the account on main network using they key file.

Answer (score 0):

Back when I ran Mist, I did notice that it used a currently running geth node on your computer, which was a nice optimization.

Often a web3 client, such as Mist or Metamask or web.js, will refuse to submit a transaction if it thinks it will fail due to gas estimates, which can be over estimates in some cases. (e.g. I tried to deploy a DAOstack dao which was supposed to cost 0.15 ETH, and had to fun my wallet with 0.65 ETH, run the TX successfully, and then empty the remaining 0.5 ETH afterwareds).

Try decreasing your gas price (the tx will be mined slower) or try funding your wallet with more about 0.1 ETH before transferring it all out, if that's what you want.

It's strange that they report different last modified times. Are the latest block numbers exactly the same? (can you be more specific about `8,xxx,xxx` in each case above?)

Comment: It wasn't the answer to my question, but eventually I found the answer and the "overestimation" part definitely helped me. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Glad you fixed it @sebastiansieber , can you add a comment to your OP saying what the problem was? Just curious.